# If $P_X=P_Y$ then $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be real integrable random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$. I want to show, that if $P_X:=P\circ X^{-1}=P_Y$ we have $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

*Proof*:

I need the following

> *Lemma*: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ and $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ be measurable spaces, let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ and let $X\colon \Omega\rightarrow\Omega'$ be measurable. Then let $\mu'=\mu\circ X^{-1}$ be the pushforward measure. Assume that $f\colon\Omega'\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\mu'$ integrable. Then $f\circ X\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ and 
>   $$\int(f\circ X)\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int f\,\mathrm{d}(\mu\circ X^{-1})$$

Now suppose $P_X=P_Y$, then
$$\int f\circ X\,\mathrm{d}P=\int f\,\mathrm{d}(P\circ X^{-1})=\int f\,\mathrm{d}P_X=\int f\,\mathrm{d}P_Y=\int f\circ Y\,\mathrm{d}P$$

If I could somehow conclude that we then must have $f\circ X=f\circ Y$ **a.s.** I could finish, because then we could just have picked a bijective integrable $f$ and could obtain $X=Y$ **a.s** and therfore reach the conclusion.

Is there a possibility to save this proof? Moreover, I suppose that there must be a much simpler argument, since this is not even proven in my book. I am not sure such a lemma is needed.

Comment: If you choose $f$ as the identity, then the LHS is $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and the RHS is $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. You can not try concluding $X=Y$ a.s., because that is not necessarily true.

Comment: You should go for $(\Omega',\mathcal A')=(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ and $f=\mathsf{id}_{\mathbb R}$. Then you can apply the lemma.

Comment: Indeed, but the lemma is not my problem. The problem is that I cannot conclude $X=Y$ a.s.

Comment: Indeed you cannot, because it does not have to be true. $X$ and $Y$ can have identical distribution (i.e.$P_X=P_Y$) without satisfying $X=Y$ a.s. But we do have $\mathbb EX=\mathbb EY$.

Comment: Consider for example $\mu = N(0,1)$ as the standard normal distribution on $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$. Then $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\omega \mapsto \omega$, has a $N(0,1)$ distribution, but so does $Y=-X$, but $X\neq Y$ a.s.

Comment: Oh, I thought too complicated, the comments before already showed me the answer ($f=id$). I then don't need anything else. Just out of curiosity, does anyone know a simpler argument for the claim?

Comment: I believe your proof is as simple as it gets and i do believe that the lemma (or something equivalent to it) is needed. In fact in the measure theory book used at my university it is stated as "the small transformation theorem".